# Angular Http subscribe - cannot assign to variable in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, subscribe

I want to retrieve data from api and assign it to some value inside the angular component. In `subscribe` I'm trying to assign the data to `loggedUser` and then call function inside this subscribe to navigate to another component with this received object. Unfortunately I got the error : **The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1**. I want to have this object set outside the subscribe too. How can I achieve this?

```
 logIn() {
      this.portfolioAppService.logIn(this.loggingUser).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loggedUser = data;
      console.log(this.loggedUser);
      console.log(data);
      this.navigateToProfile(this.loggedUser.Id);
    });
  }

  navigateToProfile(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/profile', id]);   
  }
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kneQh.png)

Comment: What do you see from the `console.log(data)`? Can you add the output to the question

Comment: I added a link to console output - these two console.logs return same objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incorrectly named property when calling `navigateToProfile`.

From your console output, I can see that the `data` object in the subscribe looks like this:

```
{
  id: 35,
  // ..
}
```

But you are calling the function like this:

```
this.navigateToProfile(this.loggedUser.Id);
```

Instead, use the property `id` (lower case)

```
this.navigateToProfile(this.loggedUser.id);
```

To narrow this problem down in the future, try being more specific in your testing. Humans are good at seeing what they want to see and will assume the problem is more complicated than it is. If you had tried `console.log(this.loggedUser.Id)`, you would have seen the result `undefined`, and worked out the problem yourself.

Comment: But loggedUser is an User type object which has a field named "Id", when I change to "id" then it doesn't know what property is it. Maybe some problems in backend?

Comment: Are you sure that your mapping is right with your User type?Can you post the  console.log(this.loggedUser)?

Comment: But this is Javascript. There is no Typescript in your browser. Typescript just allows you to model what you *expect* to happen at design time.

Comment: Your Typescript models should reflect the Javascript objects themselves. If you want your objects to have different names from the HTTP response, then map them in your service.

Comment: If not, then you need to change your Typescript model to match the HTTP response

Comment: Oh well, actually its a really sick case. When i turned it into "id" visual studio underlines it as an error and in my watch(ng build) I can see that there is an error, but it works well.

Comment: Okay, so I will turn my Typescript object to look like this received from back